# Code not working once put into a function

Tags: python, function, io

Why is the below code working as expected but once it is placed into a function. It returns unexpected results?

```
a_prm = []

folder = askdirectory()
copy = False

os.chdir(folder)
for file in glob.glob("*.prm"):
    with open(file, 'r') as prm:
        if file[:3] == 'DBA':
            for line in prm:
                if '@ATTRIB_DETAIL' in line:
                    copy = True
                elif '@BITLIST_FILES' in line:
                    copy = False
                elif copy:
                    print(line.split()[1])
```

The results that are printed are expected.

```
        if file[:3] == 'DBA':
            with open(file, 'r') as prm:
                for line in prm:
                    dimension_parse(line)

def dimensions_parse(line):
    flag = False

    if '@ATTRIB_DETAIL' in line:
        flag = True
    elif '@BITLIST_FILES' in line:
        flag = False
    elif flag:
        print(line.split()[1])
```

Returns nothing.

Comment: Share the error as well

Comment: Nothing is returned. There is no error.

Comment: What is unexpected then ?  Function won't return unless it is explicit asked to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you're resetting the `flag` (aka `copy`) value to `False` in the second version (within the function), not in the "no-routine" version, where you set it at the start only.

So behaviour is different if neither `if '@ATTRIB_DETAIL' in line` or `elif '@BITLIST_FILES' in line:` are satisfied. There's a memory effect that you don't reproduce in the second version.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your shared code, the error may be caused by defining the function after it was used.
The function should be defined before it was used.

Modified code.

```
def dimensions_parse(line):
    flag = False

    if '@ATTRIB_DETAIL' in line:
        flag = True
    elif '@BITLIST_FILES' in line:
        flag = False
    elif flag:
        print(line.split()[1])

if file[:3] == 'DBA':
            with open(file, 'r') as prm:
                for line in prm:
                    dimension_parse(line)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this but i'm getting a  list index out of range error/